# Использует GPU, но медленно считает. Настройка Theano 0.9.0 + CUDA 8.0.61 для работы на GTX Titan

Tags: нейронные-сети, cuda, gpu

Здравствуйте! У меня есть PC (GTX Titan (feb 2013) + i74820K + PCIe 3.0) и ноутбук (GTX 770M + i74700MQ + PCIe 2.0). И там и там установлено CUDA+Theano+Keras на Win10 по одной и той же инструкции (https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin). На PC выполнял установку на чистую WIN10 (после переустановки). Есть у меня модель нейронной сети на Keras. Запускаю эту сетку на ноутбуке - считает один шаг обучения 2m40s, запускаю ту же сетку на более мощном Titan - один шаг считается 4m8s. Как так?! Я уже себе всю голову сломал, не могу найти причину - уже неделю с этим мучаюсь... если тут не помогут, то даже не знаю куда ещё можно обратиться за помощью. Где копать хотя бы? Что проверить? Больше уже никаких идей не осталось.

### **Подробная х-тика железа:**

PC:

1. CPU - i74820K GPU - GTX Titan (feb 2013) (700 Серия)
2. MB - ASUS P9 X79-E WS
3. BIOS - AMI BIOS version 1704 DATE 05/08/15
4. RAM - 16Gb DDR3 NB Freq ??MHz DRAM freq 1200 MHz. FSB:DRAM 1:18, CL 10, tRCD 12, tRP 12, tRAS 31, tRFC 298, CR 2T.  (по данным CPU-z). В общем, такая http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/vengeance-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmz16gx3m2a2400c10

Notebook:
http://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/toshiba_notebook_rus/TOSHIBA-Qosmio-X70-A-K2S-i7-4700MQ-16-1TbSSHD-Blu-Ray-GTX770M-WiFi-BT-Win8-173-337-kg_161252.html

1. CPU - i74700MQ
2. GPU - GTX 770M
3. PCI - PCIe 2.0
4. BIOS - Insyde Corp. Version 1.50. Date 04/18/2014
5. RAM - 16Gb DDR3 NB Freq 3197MHz DRAM freq 799MHz. FSB:DRAM 1:6, CL 11, tRCD 11, tRP 11, tRAS 28, tRFC 208, CR 1T.  (по данным CPU-z)

Comment: Не оптимально сконфигурирована решетка для CUDA, например. Или не хватает каких-то ресурсов более мощной карты. Гадать долго можно...

Comment: Понятно, что мой вопрос задан не конкретно. Я просто даже не знаю, что нужно уточнить в этой ситуации. Подскажите, что нужно конкретизировать. Могу привести свой код на Keras, конфиг .theanorc, описать какие именно пакеты и как ставил, скажите, что нужно, я всё подробно распишу. Сейчас допишу к вопросу подробную характеристику железа.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, кстати, а что значит "не оптимально сконфигурирована решетка для CUDA"? Как это можно проверить?

Comment: Хочу проверить, а не использует ли Theano на PC компиляцию без C++. Как можно проверить какую версию с++ использует theano и использует ли вообще? Как можно проверить правильность работы CUDA, нет ли ошибок при обращении к GPU и всё ли там гладко? Мож тесты какие есть?